# How to replace `zs` in `[p| zs@(z:_) |]` with a name I generate myself?

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

If I run:

```
> runQ [p| zs@(z:_) |]
AsP zs_46 (InfixP (VarP z_47) GHC.Types.: WildP)
```

I'd like to replace `zs` and `z` with names I generate myself. I can replace `z`:

```
> let z = mkName "z"
> runQ [p| zs@($(varP z):_) |]
AsP zs_48 (InfixP (VarP z) GHC.Types.: WildP)
```

but I cannot figure out how to replace `zs`. Is there a way to do it inside quotes or do I have to resort to `asP`, etc ... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably can't. Splices only work for patterns, expressions, declarations, and types. This isn't any of those because it's just a name.

Similarly you can't splice names in other places with Template Haskell

`[d| $(mkName "f") x = x |] -- invalid`

Using `asP` as you mentioned the closest you get is

`asP (mkName "zs") [p| z:_ |]`